# Cannot Append[] Local list variable in MATHEMATICA module

Tags: list, module, wolfram-mathematica

I am having trouble understanding my mistake(s) in using local list variables in a Mathematica module. Here is boiled-down example* of what I am trying to do:

```
Module[{list = {} , a = 10}, While[a >= 0, Append[list, a--]  ]; list]
```

The expected output here is of course `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}` but in fact list is never touched and the actual output is `{}`.

What is the mistake here?

*I know about Range[]. This is the simplest example that produces the unexpected output. I wouldn't actually ever create the 10..1 list in this manner.

Comment: You need `AppendTo`.

Comment: Wow. I knew it would be something simple. Thanks.